# How to add Firebase sdk for Android library

Tags: android, firebase, android-library

I'm working on creating an Android library module for my Android applications, and I'm planning to add Firebase features to that library. As per my understanding  Firebase implementation, we need to add firebase dependencies in both app and project level gradle files. But here there is no app level gradle file for Android library module. So please help to implement Firebase SDK into my library module.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to add the firebase dependency in the build.gradle file of your library module

Answer (score 1):

> we need to add firebase dependencies in both app and project level gradle files

That's not really true.  You only need to add the Firebase libraries to the modules that directly make use of them in that module's code.  You should declare them like this using `api` so that the app modlue will include them as transitive dependencies:

```
api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-library:x.y'
```

When the module declares a dependency on the module, it will automatically pick up the all of the library dependencies declared this way.

The only thing you have to do in the app module is make sure Firebase gets initialized.  Usually that just involves adding the google play services plugin.

Comment: Hi Doug Stevenson, I have doubt, as android modules doesn't have rapid, then how it will identify the google-services.json file.?, can you give me more inputs on this, because I'm also looking for similar implementation.

Comment: Hi Doug Stevenson, I have doubt, as android modules doesn't have "applicationId", then how it will identify the google-services.json file.?, can you give me more inputs on this, because I'm also looking for similar implementation.

Comment: Library modules don't use that json config, only the app module.  The library will just use whatever is provided in the app that includes it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Doug Stevenson. But my requirement is like, I don't want to implement anything related firebase in my application. My goal is to track crashes in my android module using firebase crashlytics library.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how library modules work.  All of the code and dependencies in a library module become part of the application.  This means that it's not possible to use crashlytics to track crashes in only your library and not the rest of the app.

Comment: Okay Doug Stevenson, but here I'm developing Android SDK, not the application. My intention is like, I don't want to force the developer to add firebase libraries in his project and I don't want to expose what I'm doing in my SDK. Please let me know, if you have any suggestions.

Comment: As I said, you can't use crashlytics for this.  If you're looking for other options, do a web search.  I don't know of any.

Comment: Okay Doug Stevenson, Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: @Suresh, Even I am looking for a similar setup. Did you come up with any solution?

Comment: @PrahladVThej As per the above conversation, I came to know. Firebase SDK is only for applications not for libraries, so we cant include firebase SDK inside any library(to track library events).

Comment: I have exactly the same needing, @Suresh have you found a working solution?

Comment: @Pizzetto Didn't found any working solution for this. We have prepared our own mechanism to track.